# fasm - Как создать локальную переменную в макросе

Tags: ассемблер, макросы, fasm

Добрый день, возник вопрос как создать локальную переменную внутри макроса в ассемблере `fasm`

```
macro WriteStr str {
mov dx, str
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
}
```

Хотелось бы чтобы можно было вызвать макрос так

```
WriteStr 'Hello, world!'
```

Но не получается вполне по ясной причине что в `dx` можно поместить только адрес строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вставить строку прямо в код, перепрыгнуть через нее, а потом в `dx` записать адрес этой строки. Единственно, чтобы это работало, значения в `ds` и `cs` должны быть равны между собой.

```
macro WriteStr str {
    local ..label1
    local ..s
    jmp ..label1
..s db str, '$'
..label1:
    mov dx, ..s
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
}
```

`local` означает в данном случае, что переменные (метки) не должны быть видны снаружи макроса, две точки перед именем переменной (метки) означают, что метка будет глобальной, но не будет родительской для идущих ниже (снаружи макроса) меток, начинающихся с одной точки. Это довольно стандартный способ работы с метками в макросах fasm.

Вариант со значением по-умолчанию:

```
macro WriteStr str {
    local ..label1
    local ..s
    jmp ..label1
..s:
    if str eq
        db 'Default', '$'
    else
        db str, '$'
    end if
..label1:
    mov dx, ..s
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
}
```

`eq` используется для сравнения параметра макроса с чем-либо (в данном случае с "пустым местом")

Comment: Спасибо еще раз огромное. Если не сложно подскажи как дефолтное значение поставить?

Comment: Проблема, макрос можно вызвать только 1 раз

Comment: @Duoxx какое дефолтное значение? Вызвать можно любое количество раз, по идее должно работать. По крайней мере компилируется. Если что-то не работает, я сегодня постараюсь проверить (fasm на рабочем компе есть, а вот IDA нет).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woE6G.png

Comment: @Duoxx, скорее всего local в макросе для этой метки не указан

Comment: ойой, вот как бывает забыл local написать

Comment: Про дефолтное значение это дефолтное значение у атрибутов макроса

Comment: @Duoxx, добавил пример со значением по-умолчанию.